# Why the variable in the library class project value is changing but in the windows application project the variable value is all the time 0?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a solution with two projects.  The first one is class library and the second one is windows forms application.

I added a variable to a class in the class library project, I will not show all the code here since it's long.

```
namespace Capture.Hook
{
    public class DXHookD3D9: BaseDXHook
    {
        public DXHookD3D9(CaptureInterface ssInterface)
            : base(ssInterface)
        {
        }

        LocalHook Direct3DDevice_EndSceneHook = null;
        LocalHook Direct3DDevice_ResetHook = null;
        LocalHook Direct3DDevice_PresentHook = null;
        LocalHook Direct3DDeviceEx_PresentExHook = null;
        object _lockRenderTarget = new object();
        Surface _renderTarget;
        public static int framespersecondtodisplay = 0;

        protected override string HookName
        {
            get
            {
                return "DXHookD3D9";
            }
        }
```

The variable i added is: `framespersecondtodisplay`.

And I'm using the variable in this DXHooKD3D9 class in this code:

```
if (this.FPS.GetFPS() >= 1)
                        {
                            font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
                        }

                        if (this.TextDisplay != null && this.TextDisplay.Display)
                        {
                            font.DrawText(null, this.TextDisplay.Text, 5, 25, new SharpDX.ColorBGRA(255, 0, 0, (byte)Math.Round((Math.Abs(1.0f - TextDisplay.Remaining) * 255f))));
                            framespersecondtodisplay = (byte)Math.Round((Math.Abs(1.0f - TextDisplay.Remaining) * 255f));
                        }
```

Then in the `form1` of the windows forms application project I'm using the variable like this:

```
txtDebugLog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    fps.Frame();
                    ggg = fps.GetFPS();
                    string s = ggg.ToString("R");
                    txtDebugLog.Text = String.Format("{0:00.0}\r\n{1}", ggg.ToString("N14"), txtDebugLog.Text);
                    txtDebugLog.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", DXHookD3D9.framespersecondtodisplay.ToString(), txtDebugLog.Text);

                })               
            );
```

`txtDebugLog` is a `TextBox`

Then what I'm doing is running the windows forms application project and then in the visual studio menu I select 'Debug' > 'Attach to Process' and add two breakpoints: one in the DXHooKD3D9 class in the library class project on this line:

```
framespersecondtodisplay = (byte)Math.Round((Math.Abs(1.0f - TextDisplay.Remaining) * 255f));
```

It will stop on this line first and I step over the line, and I see a value of 24 in `framespersecontodisplay`.

I continue the execution and then it stops in the form1 breakpoint on this line:

```
txtDebugLog.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", DXHookD3D9.framespersecondtodisplay.ToString(), txtDebugLog.Text);
```

But here the value of `framespersecondtodisplay` is always 0.

If at the first breakpoint in the DXHooKD3D9 class the value there is always 24, 48, 244, or 100 - then why in form1 is it awlays 0?

Since it didn't work i tried to change the class library project code to this:

```
public static byte framespersecondtodisplay = 0;
```

But I got the same results.  So I also tried to change it from `static` to `public`:

```
public byte framespersecondtodisplay = 0;
```

And then in `form1` to create instance for the `DXHookD3D9`:

```
CaptureInterface ci;
DXHookD3D9 dxd9;
```

In constructor:

```
ci = new CaptureInterface();
dxd9 = new DXHookD3D9(ci);
```

Then:

```
txtDebugLog.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", dxd9.framespersecondtodisplay, txtDebugLog.Text);
```

But `framespersecondtodisplay` still always showing 0.

Comment: You might consider changing `framespersecondtodisplay` to a static property with a setter and getter method.  That you can put breakpoints on both the setter and getter to see where it is being called from.  This might help you understand what is going on a little better.

Comment: Serms like there are two *different* fields of the same name. Double-check your code.

Answer (score -1):

You have two different instances of the DXHooKD3D9 class.  When you call the form constructor you must pass the DXHooKD3D9 class instance to the form a save it as an internal variable.  Or you can pass the instance in any method call.  You probably are creating a 2nd instance of the class by using 'new' inside the form.

Comment: The field in question is **static**.

Comment: But if you are calling the constructor again using 'new' it will be set back to zero.  'new' recreates the instance.

Comment: Again: The field is STATIC. There's no constructor in the OP's code affecting it. Your reasoning is wrong unless there would be another constructor not shown here playing with a static field.